# How do I ignore the double but pass the rest of the ints into an array in a txt file?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am doing a Java exercise which requires me to read a file that contains numbers (includes ints and doubles) and loop them into an array. However, the code below only stops at the first double and then doesn't continue on. What do I have to do to skip over that Double (and ones that come up later on) and continue displaying the ints?

```
int index = 0;
Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
while(scan1.hasNextInt()) {
    index = index + 1;
    scan1.nextInt();
}
int[] numbers = new int[index];
Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
for(int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
    numbers[i] = scan2.nextInt();
}
return numbers;
```

Updated code:

```
public int[] readNumbers2(String fileName) throws Exception {
    int index = 0;
    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(new File(fileName)); 
    while(scan1.hasNext()) {
        if(scan1.hasNextInt()) {
            index = index + 1;
            scan1.nextInt();
        } else {
            scan1.next();
        }
    }
    int[] numbers = new int[index];
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        numbers[i] = scan2.nextInt();
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a complete answer but this loop may be better suited for you:

```
while (scan1.hasNext()) {
    if (scan1.hasNextInt()) {
       // do something with int
    } else {
       // move past non-int token
       scan1.next();
    }
}
```

So for example:

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
  Scanner scan1 = new Scanner("hello 1 2 3.5 there");
  while (scan1.hasNext()) {
    if (scan1.hasNextInt()) {
       // do something with int
       int i = scan1.nextInt();
       System.out.println(i);
    } else {
       // move past non-int token
       scan1.next();
    }
  }
}
```

prints:

```
 1
 2
```

Here's a version based on your updated code post:

```
Scanner scan1 = new Scanner("hello 1 2 3.5 there");
int index = 0;
while(scan1.hasNext()) {
    if(scan1.hasNextInt()) {
        index = index + 1;
        scan1.nextInt();
    } else {
        scan1.next();
    }
}

System.out.println("there are "+index+" integer tokens");

int[] numbers = new int[index];
int i = 0;

Scanner scan2 = new Scanner("hello 1 2 3.5 there");
while(scan2.hasNext()) {
    if(scan2.hasNextInt()) {
      numbers[i++] = scan2.nextInt();
    } else {
        scan2.next();
    }
}

for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
   System.out.println(numbers[j]);
}
```

prints

```
there are 2 integer tokens
1
2
```

Comment: I've implemented the if else statement insdie the loop. But I'm getting an error `numbers[i] = scan2.nextInt();` for InputMismatchException. I'm already throwing exceptions at the beginning of the method though.

Comment: Repost your code and go from there.  Also you can eliminate the use of two loops by using an ArrayList<Integer> and dynamically grow;  then convert to array if needed at end.

Comment: We're starting with just arrays first.

Comment: I posted another example based on your updated code.